# Modal with sliding effect

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have been trying to get modal with sliding effect and zoom in when hovering over but no luck as yet, But I managed to get to a point that picture pops up when clicking on it. This is a similar site `http://www.garysheng.com/`(Photo section). Please see the Codepen https://codepen.io/rranssa/pen/LYVyooe.

Comment: Hey Ran, Welcome to SO. Apologize that I"m having trouble understanding your question although there is a bit clarity in your description. Do you mean, How to implement sliding effect and zoom in capabilities for a modal when hovering?

Comment: Hey Manjunath, Really appreciate your comment, yes that's what I want to achieve but the sliding capability has to be once it's clicked. If you check the site mentioned you will how it flows. Thanks, heaps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [lightGallery](https://sachinchoolur.github.io/lightGallery/docs/)

It is simple and you don't have to implement it by yourself,
all you need to do is to add mentioned link in [documentation](https://sachinchoolur.github.io/lightGallery/docs/) and then use it like below:

```
<div id="lightgallery">
  <a href="img/img1.jpg">
      <img src="img/thumb1.jpg" />
  </a>
  <a href="img/img2.jpg">
      <img src="img/thumb2.jpg" />
  </a>
</div>


<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#lightgallery").lightGallery(); 
    });
</script>
```

You can enable and disable options by passing an object to it like this:

```
$('#lightgallery').lightGallery({
    mode: 'lg-fade',
    cssEasing : 'cubic-bezier(0.25, 0, 0.25, 1)'
    ......
});
```

all options are available in link below: 
https://sachinchoolur.github.io/lightGallery/docs/api.html

Comment: Hi Hhakib, Thanks for your answer and it's working but still I couldn't find the way to zoom in when hovering over the image.  I tried adding id responsive image data-responsive as https://sachinchoolur.github.io/lightGallery/demos/responsive.html but not sure where I'm wrong at.

Comment: Hi Shakib, I managed to get it correct. Thanks for your initiation.
Ran

Comment: @Ran my pleasure.